# XSLT code to read the prefix and name space element from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to read the below XML element value using XSLT code.

Input XML:

```
    <ns0:PrintCertificateByContractNumber xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
    <ns0:ContractNumber>123</ns0:ContractNumber>
    </ns0:PrintCertificateByContractNumber>
```

Below XSLT I am try to read the value

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <tem:PrintCertificateByContractNumber>
                    <tem:ContractNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns0:PrintCertificateByContractNumber/ns0:ContractNumber"/>
                    </tem:ContractNumber>
                </tem:PrintCertificateByContractNumber>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <tem:PrintCertificateByContractNumber>
                    <tem:ContractNumber>123</tem:ContractNumber>
                </tem:PrintCertificateByContractNumber>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

please any one help me with XSLT code to get the above XML output

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what errors do you face. 
Please do not ask for ready-made code directly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a prefix (`ns0`) without binding it a namespace first. Try changing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
```

to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
```

Comment: It works for me: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvB

Comment: namespaces are getting added in the output xml   `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common" xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ep41="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities" xmlns:ep4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common">
 ` need to ignore the ns0,ns1 and ns2.

Comment: No, that is NOT what happens in the example you gave - see the demo in the link above..